# Get continuous list of integers

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 1000 (inclusive of 1000).

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i=i+1)
{
       Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

But, I do remember a single line of code that I myself used before. Like below:

```
Enumerable.TheMethodGives1To1000(Console.WriteLine);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @manuchao: A one liner to generate a sequence of integral numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you need is [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method which generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range. It returns `IEnumerable<int>` object.
And for printing the elements in this collection we can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It performs the specified action on each element of the `List<T>`. And in case of single argument you can pass function by itself.

***So, the result is:***

```
 Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: In case of single argument you can pass function by itself `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`.

Comment: `ToList()` is redundent and I removed it.

Comment: @leppi `ToList()` is not redundant because `.ForEach` belongs to `List<T>`

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 999))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: A minor correction: Enumerable.Range(1, 1000). Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Sequence can be created with `Enumerable.Range`.

Calling `Console.Write` with Linq queries is somewhat unusual as it does not return value.

You can construct string first and than print it i,e:

```
var result = String.Join("\n", Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i=> i.ToString()));
```

Or use `ForEach` of `List`

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)
```

Or return value along with call to `WriteLine` in Select:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return 0;});
```

Comment: No need for `.Select(i => i.ToString())`, `String.Join()` works with `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @Alexei: I accepted the other answer because of the lower score, though this was the first answer. Thanks a lot Alexei.